# but there is no value for it to be borrowed from

Tags: rust

I have the code simplified version of which looks like the following:

```
fn main() {
  method1(true);
}

fn method1(cond: bool) -> (&[u8], String) {
  let ret1 = if cond {
    let a = "a string in base64".as_bytes().from_base64();
    a.unwrap().as_slice()
  } else {
    [] // how can I return an empty array? Should I return vector instead?
  };

  (ret1, "aaa".to_string())
}
```

The error:

```
error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
test1.rs:7 fn method1(cond: bool) -> (&[u8], String) {
                                      ^~~~~
test1.rs:7:28: 7:33 help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
test1.rs:7 fn method1(cond: bool) -> (&[u8], String) {
                                      ^~~~~
test1.rs:7:28: 7:33 help: consider giving it a 'static lifetime
test1.rs:7 fn method1(cond: bool) -> (&[u8], String) {
                                      ^~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

The bottom line is, I want to return a tuple of an array and a string (String or &str) from a method, how can I do that?

Comment: I recommend you read an article I wrote which covers this area fairly decently: http://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-fizzbuzz.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't.

You can do this:

```
fn main() {
  method1(true);
}

fn method1(cond: bool) -> (&'static [u8], String) {
  // ' <-- un-confuse SO syntax highlighting...
  let ret1 = if cond {
    b"some hard-coded data"
  } else {
    b""
  };

  (ret1, "aaa".to_string())
}
```

> **Note**: `b"..."` is just a short-hand syntax for creating `&'static [u8]` values.

But you can't return a reference to data which isn't owned by something outside the function.  If the data isn't statically known, then yes, you'll have to return a `Vec<u8>` in order to pass ownership out.

**Revision to address question in comments.**

Other things that don't work:

- `fn method1<'a>...` - firstly, this doesn't change the fact that to pass a reference out, you have to be referring to something which will still exist after the function exits.  Outside of globals (which you should almost *never* use, **especially** in a case like this), there's no way to summnon a long-lived value into existence outside your function.  You *have* to return a value that owns its contents, and that can *never* be a borrow.

  Declaring a generic lifetime parameter doesn't change that.
- `&([u8], String)` - this isn't valid.  First, it has the exact same problem as originally: you can't return a borrow to something you've created.  Secondly, it contains `[u8]`, which is a dynamically sized type.  You cannot have a dynamically sized type in a tuple; the only position (that I'm aware of) in which they are valid is at the very end of a struct, and *that* causes the struct itself to become dynamically sized.  You cannot pass, return or store dynamically sized values.
- `(&[u8], &str)` - this has the same problem as originally, except now the second tuple value is *also* borrowed.  There are cases where the compiler *can* guess the lifetime for you, but this is not one of them (and I don't want to get into a description of the lifetime elision rules here).

Comment: Can't I use something like `<&'a>...` somehow?

Comment: why should it be `(&'static [u8], String)` and not, say `&([u8], String)` or `(&[u8], &str)` or something else?

Comment: is there any way to create `&'static [u8]` without `b`?

Comment: `static STUFF: &'static [u8] = &[0, 1, 2];`