# error: `var` does not live long enough

Tags: rust

I can't deal with an error in this code:

```
extern crate serialize;

use std::collections::TreeMap;
use serialize::base64;
use serialize::base64::{ToBase64, FromBase64};

fn main() {
  method1(true);
}

fn method1(cond: bool) -> (&'static [u8], String) {
  let ret1 = if cond {
    let a = "a string in base64".as_bytes();
    let b = a.from_base64();
    let c = b.unwrap();
    let d = c.as_slice();
    d  // error: `c` does not live long enough


    // or 
    // "a string in base64".as_bytes().from_base64().unwrap().as_slice() - the same error

   // or
   // static a: &'static [u8] = &[1]; - no error, but that's not what I want
  } else {
    b""
  };

  (ret1, "aaa".to_string())
}
```

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [but there is no value for it to be borrowed from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247142/but-there-is-no-value-for-it-to-be-borrowed-from) (this ground was covered in that question of yours from only a few hours earlier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d` is a reference to data created in that same scope, the scope within the braces of `if cond`. When you leave that scope, the data is gone, so what would the reference `d` point to? That's why you get the error. You can return it as a `Vec<u8>`, which you already have in `c`.

Comment: Is there any way to return [u8] from method1?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: No. `[u8]` is dynamically-sized which means the compiler would not know how much stack space to allocate for the return value. This is usually solved via an indirection. And this is what `Vec<u8>` is doing internally.